# Creating an array that is consisted of unique numbers

Tags: javascript, unique-index

I'm developing a simple game that allows user to generate from 1 to 5 Cat images from certain Cat Api. Then, after clicking start button the app generates shadow copies of those cats(with low opacity). Game will be later about dragging bottom images and fiting them to their shadow copies, that are randomly positioned(only then game makes sense). Then I'm planning make some futher features like time counter, points etc. etc. just for learning purposes.

But what am struggling with is creating a unique random number(that'll be index of particular cat) an will not be repeated during iteration...

Here is the code

```
 const newArray = []; // 


const catsArrayList = [...catBoardCopy.querySelectorAll('.cat')] //Array with cat images

function randomizeIndex() { // randomize an index number
    let randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * catsArrayList.length - 1) + 1);
    console.log(randomIndex);

    return randomIndex;
}

catsArrayList.forEach(catElement => { // here I am iterating over an array with cats which length is for example 5(this is max actually)

    newArray.push(catsArrayList[randomizeIndex()]); // and pushing those elements with randomly generated index to the new array

})

newArray.forEach(newCat => {

    shadowCatsContainer.appendChild(newCat); // here random cats are finally put to html container
})
```

And all of this work until the point when one of those random numbers is at least one time repeated... of course this happens actually 90% of time.

Im supposing it won't be simple solution to that. I tried so hard to make it work with different techniques, different loops, different array methods and nothing :( Also please take note that Im beginner so I need exhaustive guidance of what is going on :)

Have a nice day.

Comment: Standard way to do this in a case like yours is to fill an array with the indexes in order, then shuffle the array. You can then pluck numbers from the array and never get a duplicate.

Comment: Would using Set be an option for you?

Comment: Also instead of looping through an array and pushing values to new one consider using Array.map function.

Comment: What number range do you want? Example: 1 - 100 ?

Comment: Looks like the indexes into the cat array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close; you can just remove the items that you're assigning to the new array from the source array so you don't use it twice.

```
const cats = [...catBoardCopy.querySelectorAll('.cat')]

function randomIndex() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * cats.length);
}

cats.forEach(catElement => {
    const index = randomIndex();
    shadowCatsContainer.appendChild(cats[index]);
    cats.splice(index, 1);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simply shuffle an array:

```js
const cats = ['Tigger', 'Smokey', 'Kitty', 'Simba', 'Sassy'];

function shuffle(array, n = 500) {
    const output = array.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        swap(output, getRandomInt(0, output.length), getRandomInt(0, output.length))
    }

    return output;
}

function swap(array, i, j) {
    const temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

const shadowedCats = shuffle(cats);
console.log(cats);
console.log(shadowedCats);
console.log(shuffle(cats));
```

Answer (score 0):

An example using array. Here I created an array with the possible numbers, it goes from 0 to the number of elements contained in the 'catsArrayList' array. If for example 'catsArrayList' has 3 elements, then the array with the possible numbers will be equal to: [0, 1, 2]

The idea now is to draw a random number from that array and then remove it from the list, and then we can go on repeating the process without getting repeated values.

e.g.

```js
let catsArrayList = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6'] // example


let numbers = [...Array(catsArrayList.length).keys()]
let lengthnumbers = numbers.length


for(let i = 1; i <= lengthnumbers; i++) {
  let randoms = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)
  console.log(i + 'º number: ' + numbers.splice(randoms, 1))
}
```

*Click on 'Run code snippet' a few times and you will see that you will get different, non-repetitive random numbers*